# syntax error on batch File to create a timestamp directory

Tags: scripting, syntax-error, batch-file

I tried the script below to create a timestamp directory in one of my drives, for some reason is giving me a syntax error on the last string where it create the directory. See below.

```
:: Code begins....
pause
W:
pause
cd W:\VL2000_AMF\AMF_Archive
pause
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=. " %%i in ('date /t') do (
set Day=%%i
set Month=%%j
set Year=%%k
)
pause
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=: " %%i in ('time /t') do (
set Hour=%%i
set Minute=%%j
set Second=%%k
)
pause
md %1\%Year%-%Month%-%Day%
pause
:: Code ends....
```

Comment: What version of Windows are you running on? When I try something similar to the above, month is set to "08/17/2010" which will lead to a syntax error when it is substituted into the md command line.

Comment: Windows XP Professional.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following on Windows 2000 and 2003 to get year, month, and day from the date command output. Unfortunately, I no longer have any XP systems to see if this will work there.

```
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (
echo "Day=%%i"
echo "Month=%%j"
echo "Year=%%k"
)
```

What is the format of "date /t" and "time /t" output on XP?

Comment: Yes, the date output should depend upon locale. However, I don't know if that is true with XP or not since I no longer have any systems with it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your date is coming back as `mm.dd.yyyy` (separated by dots, and with the fields in the order you expect)?  If the process's locale is not what you expect, you might be ending up with `%Day%` as something like `8/17/2010`, which would cause `md` to report a syntax error as it tries to interpret `/17` and `/2010` as options.